# Wordpress SQL query to sort parent posts base on child post's IDs

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I have a page that list parent posts & child post. However, with this query the sorting is only sort by parent post ID.

```
$args = array(
        'order'     => 'DESC',
        'orderby'   => 'ID',
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => -1,
        'showposts' => $latest_post
        );
$wp_query = new wp_query($args);
```

How can I list the parent posts but sort by child post ID? Given:

- Parent post: post
- Child post (custom post type): child

Thank you so much.

Comment: what are the parent and child collum names?

Comment: Hi, when using WP Data Access plugin for Wordpress to browse the database, I still see only the ID column, no other names for the parents and childs, in Posts Table.